# No line numbers in stacktrace on OS X with DNX - dnxcore50 - am I missing a PDB-file?

Tags: c#, macos, terminal, stack-trace, dnx

Trying out a [Console-application](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html) in OSX, by having [installed .NET for Mac](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html). The stack trace in the Terminal looks as follow:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ConfigEditor.XmlLoader.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ConfigEditor.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How can I get the stack trace to output the file name and line numbers? Do I need a pdb-file as in Windows, and how do I get one?

My project consists of three files at this time:

- Program.cs
- project.json
- project.lock.json

And I run the app with `dnx . run`.

Comment: You'll first need code that can read debug info files to dig out the file+line number info.  Done by DIA on Windows, a COM component that's a friendly wrapper around the DbgHelp api.  Don't hold your breath waiting for this to be available on OSX, I kinda doubt that's a priority right now.  Or contribute it :)

Comment: Oh, I thought such a feature had higher priority! Cheers.